# Building a GeoDataFrame out of a shapely GeometryCollection with shapely 2.0.0 -> ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely, pandas, geometrycollection

I successfully used to build a [GeoDataFrame](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.html) out of a shapely [GeometryCollection](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/shapely.GeometryCollection.html) (hereafter `gc`) as `gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(gc)` but I'm now facing this error with shapely `2.0.0`:

```py
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(gc)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/geopandas/geodataframe.py", line 135, in __init__
    super().__init__(data, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 781, in __init__
    raise ValueError("DataFrame constructor not properly called!")
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

Code to reproduce the error:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Point, GeometryCollection

p = Point(51, -1)
l = LineString([(52, -1), (49, 2)])
gc = GeometryCollection([p, l])

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(gc)

# Previously, with shapely 1.8.5:
gdf
>:
                          0
0             POINT (51 -1)
1  LINESTRING (52 -1, 49 2)
```

When I print `gc` with shapely `2.0.0`, it gives:

```py
gc
>:
  <GEOMETRYCOLLECTION (POINT (51 -1), LINESTRING (52 -1, 49 2))>
```

Whereas with shapely `1.8.5` it was:

```py
gc
>:
  <shapely.geometry.collection.GeometryCollection object at 0x7fab2c6062c0>
```

Also:

```
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry':gc})

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/geopandas/geodataframe.py", line 135, in __init__
    super().__init__(data, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 664, in __init__
    mgr = dict_to_mgr(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy, typ=manager)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 493, in dict_to_mgr
    return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, columns, index, dtype=dtype, typ=typ, consolidate=copy)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 118, in arrays_to_mgr
    index = _extract_index(arrays)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 656, in _extract_index
    raise ValueError("If using all scalar values, you must pass an index")
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

Therefore, how to properly build a GeoDataFrame from a shapely GeometryCollection in GeoPandas with shapely `2.0.0`?

##### Version info:

- geopandas `0.12.2`
- pandas `1.5.3`
- shapely `2.0.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building a GeoDataFrame out of a shapely GeometryCollection is done as follows with shapely >= 2.0.0:

```py
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(gc.geoms)
gdf
>:
                          0
0             POINT (51 -1)
1  LINESTRING (52 -1, 49 2)
```

See also: [Access individual elements of a GeometryCollection with shapely >= 2.0.0](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/451213/access-individual-elements-of-a-geometrycollection-with-shapely-2-0-0)

Answer (score 0):

A GeoDataFrame needs a geometry field (if not, it is a DataFrame). Therefore the correct method to create it is:

```
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry':gc})
print(gdf)
                                       geometry
0                         POINT (51.00000 -1.00000)
1  LINESTRING (52.00000 -1.00000, 49.00000 2.00000)
```

Note that print gc with shapely 1.8.5 and 2.0.0 is equivalent

```
gc
<shapely.geometry.collection.GeometryCollection object at 0x11f0eb2e8>
```

but

```
print(gc)
GEOMETRYCOLLECTION (POINT (51 -1), LINESTRING (52 -1, 49 2))
# or
gc.wkt
'GEOMETRYCOLLECTION (POINT (51 -1), LINESTRING (52 -1, 49 2))'
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Unfortunately, `gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry':gc})` raises another error. See the update in the main post.