# Accessing individual elements of GeometryCollection with shapely >= 2.0.0

Tags: python, shapely, geometrycollection

From the code available here: https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/shapely.GeometryCollection.html:

```py
from shapely import LineString, Point

p = Point(51, -1)
l = LineString([(52, -1), (49, 2)])
gc = GeometryCollection([p, l])
```

How can I access the individual elements of the [GeometryCollection](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/shapely.GeometryCollection.html) with shapely >= 2.0.0?

I've tried the most simplistic/pythonic way without any success:

```py
list(gc)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'GeometryCollection' object is not iterable
```

So, if the object is not iterable, I guess it will be hard to extract every single feature out of the geometry collection for the moment.

And in a similar way, as suggested in [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/182985/how-to-access-members-of-geometrycollection-python/384757) thread:

```py
gc[0]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'GeometryCollection' object is not subscriptable
```

The object is neither subscriptable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this code instead:

```py
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.geometry import LineString
from shapely.geometry import GeometryCollection

p = Point(51, -1)
l = LineString([(52, -1), (49, 2)])
gc = GeometryCollection([p, l])

pnt = gc.geoms[0]  # return point
print(pnt.x)
```

Answer (score 6):

`.geoms` was absolutely a proper decision based on the deprecation e.g. in version 1.8.1.

> `ShapelyDeprecationWarning`: Iteration over multi-part geometries is
> deprecated and will be removed in Shapely 2.0. Use the `geoms`
> property to access the constituent parts of a multi-part geometry.
>
> `ShapelyDeprecationWarning`: `__len__` for multi-part geometries is
> deprecated and will be removed in Shapely 2.0. Check the length of the
> `geoms` property instead to get the  number of parts of a multi-part
> geometry.
>
> `ShapelyDeprecationWarning`: `__getitem__` for multi-part geometries is
> deprecated and will be removed in Shapely 2.0. Use the `geoms`
> property to access the constituent parts of a multi-part geometry.

I just wanted to mention another possibility through the [`mapping()`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/1.8.0/manual.html#shapely.geometry.mapping) and [`shape()`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/1.8.0/manual.html#shapely.geometry.shape) methods:

```py
from shapely.geometry import mapping, shape, LineString, Point, GeometryCollection

p = Point(51, -1)
l = LineString([(52, -1), (49, 2)])
gc = GeometryCollection([p, l])

print(shape(mapping(gc)['geometries'][0]))
print(shape(mapping(gc)['geometries'][1]))
```

will result in:

```py
POINT (51 -1)
LINESTRING (52 -1, 49 2)
```

Answer (score 4):

I was [told](https://github.com/shapely/shapely/discussions/1750#discussioncomment-4863877) by one of the shapely's maintainer that now, one has to use the `.geoms` attribute to access individual geometries. E.g.:

```py
list(gc.geoms)
>:
  [<POINT (51 -1)>, <LINESTRING (52 -1, 49 2)>]
```

So as Hornbydd said in his answer, accessing a single element is done with a subscript on `.geoms`, e.g.:

```py
gc.geoms[0]
>:
  <POINT (51 -1)>

gc.geoms[1]
>:
  <LINESTRING (52 -1, 49 2)>
```